# Can you apply a regular expression for a param in Svelte's Routify?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, routify

I currently have a route which I have configured to be `(foo|bar)`. So now my child route of `example` accepts the following combinations:

```
/foo/example
/bar/example
```

However, when I navigate to my example page, `$page.path` is `/(foo|bar)/example` so I'm not able to tell if the first param is `foo` or `bar` unless I check `location.pathname`.

On the other hand, if I rename my directory to be called `[myParam]` instead of `(foo|bar)`, all types of strings would match this route, like:

```
/i-dont-want-that/example
/or-that/example
```

So what directory name should I use to create a param called `myParam` that satisfies the regular expression `(foo|bar)`?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way native way to do this in Routify2, but you could do something like this.

```html
<!-- root _layout.svelte -->
<script>
  import { params, goto } from '@roxi/routify'
  if (!['foo', 'bar'].includes($params.myParam)
    $goto('/404')
</script>
```

It's worth noting, static paths always take precedence over dynamic paths, so you don't have to worry about conflicting paths.